# Are explicit method arguments a good idea? - Idiomatic Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm writing some numerical code that uses classes for the elements of the finite element model.
I appreciate the functional coding style that passes one set of arguments into a function and passes out one result, but I wonder if using this style with classes and methods might be a bit much. Am I showing my numerical roots?

I'd like to know:

1. What is the idiomatic way to pass arguments to methods?
2. If I want to make the data flow explicit, how far can I go before leaving the realms of pythonic good taste?

By way of example, I have three classes below:

**StandardPoint** represents what I believe to be common Python code, but it implicitly passes state, making the code less clear and more difficult to test. It does look quite neat, however.

**ExplicitPoint** makes the mutation of state more explicit and is probably my preferred option. This is less neat and still implicitly passes state into the method. Unit-testing would still require mock objects I think.

**ExtremePoint** makes all the data-passing explicit but of course the higher level code is noisier (four selfs on one line). Unit-testing the method becomes very easy.  The static method is almost certainly a step too far, but makes sense as you don't need self for state.  The top-level function is more pythonic (I suggest) but only if more than one class needs it.

```
from math import sqrt

class StandardPoint(object):
    """Is this idiomatic python?"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._calc_distance()

    def _calc_distance(self):
        self.distance = sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

class ExplicitPoint(object):
    """Explicit setting of attributes but implicit passing-in of data."""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.distance = None
        # ...
        self.distance = self._calc_distance()

    def _calc_distance(self):
        return sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

class ExtremePoint(object):
    """Explicit data passing everywhere."""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.distance = None
        self.distance = self._calc_distance(self.x, self.y)
        # or even
        # self.distance = self._calc_distance_static(self.x, self.y)

    def _calc_distance(self, x, y):
        return sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

    @staticmethod
    def _calc_distance_static(x, y):
        return sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

def calc_distance(x, y):
    """Top-level function for use by many classes."""
    return sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
```

Comment: `StandardPoint` and `ExplicitPoint` are identical... its not like you are warming up the variable or something. `ExplicitPoint` is the normal way to reduce the state of the object. Back to the first two examples, don't calculate on init... you could make it fancy with the `@property` decorator or you could memoize it (remember the x, y, and result from the last calculation). You could even write setters for x and y so that its recalculated in the background every time one of them changes. I've done this in GUI apps where I want results to change dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

The most natural way to do this would be:

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def distance(self):
        return sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)
```

It's just weird and unnecessary to pass instance variables to a method.

All of your examples create the problem that if `x` and `y` ever change, then `distance` will be incorrect unless the developer remembers to update it as well. You want to be calculating `distance` on-the-fly.